# How to import an two values array to highcharts from csv file

Tags: arrays, csv, split, highcharts

I have tried to import a single array to highcharts from csv file succesfully, just like [data-from-csv](http://www.highcharts.com/studies/data-from-csv.htm)
said. And I can also use series like

```
        series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data:[[0, 15], [1, 50], [2, 56.5], [4, 46.5], [8, 22.1], [16, 20]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [[0, 10], [1, 50], [2, 50], [4, 40], [8, 22], [16, 25]
    }]
```

in the javascript field.

But when I want to import the two values array from a csv file, the chart doesn't work. code

```
$.get('data.csv', function(data) {
// Split the lines
var lines = data.split('\n');
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
    var items = line.split(';');

    // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
    var series = {
        data: []
    };
    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
        if (itemNo == 0) {
            series.name = item;
        } else {
            series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
        }
    });
    options.series.push(series);
});

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

data.csv :

```
data; [1, 12.97]; [4, 52.16]; [16, 208.96]; [64, 663.84]
```

the charts can show the array name "data" , but can't show the line, can anyone help me with it , thanks~

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that item in the following line

```
series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
```

is not a float, but an array of two values. I think you want the line to read something like:

```
series.data.push(JSON.parse(item));
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I searched javascript API and find parseFloat only return the first number in the string. But JSON.parse is a jquery API, we can't use it in a javascript function.